# Running Docker Under Vagrant

Tags: docker, vagrant

I'm having a puzzling issue with Vagrant 1.7.2 running a Docker image. I'm trying to launch a plain vanilla Docker container based on this Postgres image. If I understand correctly Docker should *not* be trying to ssh into this image, but simply spinning it up and exposing port 5432.

My Vagrant file is as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5432, host: 5432
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.image = "tutum/jboss"
    d.ports = ["5432:5432"]
    d.env = {
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
    }
    d.has_ssh = false
  end
end
```

Output from `vagrant up --provider=docker` is:

```
vagrant up --provider=docker
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    default: Vagrant will now create or start a local VM to act as the Docker
    default: host. You'll see the output of the `vagrant up` for this VM below.
    default:
    default: Checking if box 'mitchellh/boot2docker' is up to date...
    default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
    default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 => 2375 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
    default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    default: Booting VM...
    default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

At this point the process just times out trying to ssh into the image.

Answer (score 4):

As @Thomasleveil mentioned, has_ssh is referring to the container, not the host VM that vagrant boots on Windows and Mac machines.

If you run the 'vagrant global-status' command you'll see that there are actually two vagrant boxes being created:

```
id       name    provider   state     directory                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1172194  default virtualbox running   {dir}/.vagrant.d/data/docker-host    
d19539e  default docker     preparing {your image}
```

You'll have to destroy the docker-host image by calling 'vagrant destroy {docker-host id}' , and then add the following line to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.ssh.insert_key = false
```

Call 'vagrant up --provider=docker' one more time and you should be alright.

As for why you even need to add this line in the first place, [this github issue](https://github.com/YungSang/boot2docker-vagrant-box/issues/17) explains things well.

AndyShinn writes:

> It looks like on first up, Vagrant replaces the insecure SSH key with a generated one. Then on halt / up again, that key is reverted back to the insecure key in the VM, but Vagrant is trying to use the newly generated public key to SSH. Looks like this is because /home/docker/.ssh is part of the root mount on tmpfs.

Answer (score 1):

such a Vagrantfile will make Vagrant create a VM (running ssh) to act as a Docker host. Once that VM is created, booted, and provisioned (through ssh), Vagrant will tell the Docker host to pull the `tutum/jboss` docker image and run a container (which does not have ssh) for it.

Your issue is Vagrant failing to connect through ssh to the VM `mitchellh/boot2docker` which is supposed to act as a Docker host.